# How can ensure that iframe loaded in ASP.Net Core Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

i have simple project ASP.Net Core with Razor. In this project I have single page that just open iframe. That works fine, but I want to know when iframe not loaded, is it possible?

```
@page
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions
@model IndexModel

<iframe src="@Model.BuildIFrameReference(HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl())"
        frameborder="0"
        style="overflow: hidden;overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: hidden;height: 100%;width: 100%;position: absolute;top: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px;bottom: 0px"
        height="100%"
        width="100%"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Duskone39,any update?

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer! I try but its not work for me, so I try check iframe url before render html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I choose different way to do this.I add new middleware that ping iframe url. If url for iframe returned not successed status code or have X-Frame-Options: Deny header I make redirect to default page.

```
public class CheckIframeUrlMiddleware
  {
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CheckIframeUrlMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
      _next = next;
      _client = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IframeReferenceBuilder _builder)
    {
      try
      {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(_builder.BuildIFrameReference(context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()));

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          context.Response.Redirect(_builder.Settings.RedirectDomain);

        if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Frame-Options", out var values) && values.Contains("DENY"))
          context.Response.Redirect(_builder.Settings.RedirectDomain);

        await _next.Invoke(context);
      }
      catch
      {
        context.Response.Redirect(_builder.Settings.RedirectDomain);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the iframe's load event.

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src=...></iframe>
@section Scripts
{
<script>
$('#myFrame').on('load', function () {
        var iframeBody = this.contentDocument.body;
        console.log('iframe loaded, body is: ', iframeBody);
        alert("iframe loaded");
    });
</script>
 }
```